# Inserting & Printing Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am testing out my linked list functions with this snippet of code but I cannot get it to print correctly. I want the program to print out `HELLO` but instead it prints out `LO`. This is my first time working with linked lists so any help is appreciated.

I did try putting the `print` function after every insertion of a letter to see if the `insert` functions were working and they were. It would print out each letter but after inserting all the letters and printing once again it only prints out the last two letters. So I believe the problem is not with the `insert` functions but I could be wrong.

This is my header file:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char DATA_TYPE;


typedef struct node_t
{
    DATA_TYPE item;
    struct node_t* next;
} node;

typedef struct
{
    node* head;
    int len;
} linkedlist_t;

void init_list(linkedlist_t* plist);
void insert_first(linkedlist_t* plist, DATA_TYPE item);
void insert_middle(linkedlist_t* plist, int pos, DATA_TYPE item);
void insert_last(linkedlist_t* plist, DATA_TYPE item);
void print(linkedlist_t* plist);
```

Functions:

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

void init_list(linkedlist_t* plist)
{

    plist->head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    plist->head->next = NULL;
    plist->len = 0;
}


void insert_first(linkedlist_t* plist, DATA_TYPE item)
{
    node* cur, *newNode;

    newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->item = item;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    cur = plist->head;

    newNode->next = cur->next;
    cur->next = newNode;
    plist->len++;
}



void insert_middle(linkedlist_t* plist, int pos, DATA_TYPE item)
{

    node* cur, *newNode;
    if(pos < 0 || pos > plist->len){
        exit(1);
    }

    newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->item = item;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    cur = plist->head;
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    newNode->next = cur->next;
    cur->next = newNode;
    plist->len++;
}

void insert_last(linkedlist_t* plist, DATA_TYPE item)
{

    node* cur, *newNode;

    newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->item = item;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    cur = plist->head;
    while(cur->next != NULL){
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    newNode->next = cur->next;
    cur->next = newNode;
    plist->len++;

}


void print(linkedlist_t* plist)
{
    node* cur;
    while(cur != NULL){
        printf("%c", cur->item);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Main function:

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {


    linkedlist_t list;

    init_list(&list);

    insert_first(&list, 'H');
    insert_middle(&list, 1, 'E');
    insert_middle(&list, 2, 'L');
    insert_middle(&list, 3, 'L');
    insert_last(&list, 'O');

    print(&list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *cannot get it to print correctly*. Can you please give the exact behaviour? *I think I know where the problem lies*. Can you please give us that info?

Comment: @kaylum I updated the question, hopefully it is a little more complete now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print` function does not use the parameter `plist`.

You most likely want something like:

```c
void print(linkedlist_t* plist)
{
    node* cur = plist->head;
    while(cur != NULL){
        printf("%c", cur->item);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Also `init_list` is adding a node with an uninitialized character to the start of the list.